# What is the basis of the vectors contained in the basis of a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

What is the basis of the vectors contained in the basis of a vector space?
Are the vectors in the basis by default written in terms of the standard basis of the vector space they span? Or there's more to this?

Comment: How do you define a basis of a basis?

Comment: @WlodAA I think I got it.  
Say we have some basis E of some vector space V, then the elements (vectors) of V are written as $(...,...,...,...)_E$, that is, they can be written as a linear combination of the vectors in E. But since the vectors in E are by definition also in V, they can also be written as linear combinations of the vectors in E. Hence, they must be represented as E-coordinates, just like every other vector contained in V.  They are written with respect to the basis E.

Comment: Given a basis $\ E,\ $ each vector admits a **unique** linear combination representation in E. Thus each element $\ e \in E\ $ is represented **uniquely** as $\ e = 1\cdot e.\ $ There is really nothing to it. You may be confusing the notion of a *generating set* and *basis*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Note:** The basis of a vector space is not a vector space.

So one cannot talk about the basis of the basis vectors. It does not make sense.

Comment: Hi, I'm not talking about the basis of the basis.  I'm talking about the vectors in that basis.  They are written as coordinates, right? But coordinates of what?  e.g. (1, 0, 2) could be a vector in a basis, but what are the 1, 0 and 2 referring to?

Comment: Only if your space is $\Bbb R_n$ you will have basis elements in the coordinate form. In general this need not be true. For instance what is the basis for $P_n(\Bbb R)$:=The space of all polynomials of degree upto $n$? Are the basis elements in the coordinate form?

Comment: So, they are really just lists of characters referring to a specific property of the elements of the vector space?

Comment: Not exactly. I think you should go step by step. 1st try to understand a vector space, work out some examples, get a feel for it. Then move to the basis of a vector space and so on. Go slow, go strong!

Comment: Hold on.  Let me try again.  Say we have some basis E of some vector space V, then the elements (vectors) of V are written as $(...,...,...,...)_E$, that is, they can be written as a linear combination of the vectors in E.  But since the vectors in E are by definition also in V, they can also be written as linear combinations of the vectors in E.  Hence, they must be represented as *E-coordinates*, just like every other vector contained in V.